# Button click inside div click nothing working

Tags: knockout.js

I have a button click event inside a div which also has a click event. If a user clicks the button, only insideClick should execute not outsideClick. Can someone share some insight?

https://jsfiddle.net/s4om9y1y/

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: goal" />
<div data-bind="click: outsideClick">
  Outside click.

  <button data-bind="click: insideClick">
    Inside click.
  </button>
</div>



function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.goal = ko.observable(3);

  self.outsideClick = function() {
    alert('outside click');
  };
  self.insideClick = function() {
    alert('inside click');
  };

}

var vm = new AppViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: do you really want div as click with inside button with click or just a button?

Comment: If user clicks the button, the div click event should not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `clickBubble` binding with the paramter `false` to your inner binding:

```
<button data-bind="click: insideClick, clickBubble: false">
  Inside click.
</button>
```

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-4-preventing-the-event-from-bubbling):

> By default, Knockout will allow the click event to continue to bubble up to any higher level event handlers. For example, if your element and a parent of that element are both handling the click event, then the click handler for both elements will be triggered. **If necessary, you can prevent the event from bubbling by including an additional binding that is named clickBubble and passing false to it, ... :**

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgn32feh/).